# How to use vdbench to do multiple operations concurrently on the 3 file system

Tags: io, storage

I want to use following `vdbench` parameter files to do muliple operations concurrently on the 3 file system, however, the execute failed as in below.

Can some one help to check what is wrong in the paremeter file?

```
data_errors=1
fsd=fsd1,anchor=/vdbench1,depth=2,width=2,files=100,size=14823424
fsd=fsd2,anchor=/vdbench2,depth=2,width=2,files=100,size=14823424
fsd=fsd3,anchor=/vdbench3,depth=2,width=2,files=100,size=22245376
fwd=fwd11,fsd=fsd*,operation=mkdir
fwd=fwd12,fsd=fsd*,operation=write
fwd=fwd13,fsd=fsd*,operation=read
fwd=fwd14,fsd=fsd*,operation=open
fwd=fwd15,fsd=fsd*,operation=close
fwd=fwd16,fsd=fsd*,operation=setattr
fwd=fwd17,fsd=fsd*,operation=getattr
fwd=fwd18,fsd=fsd*,operation=create
fwd=fwd19,fsd=fsd*,operation=delete
rd=rd1,fwd=fwd1*,format=yes,fwdrate=max
```

The output reads:

```
00:02:26.312 input argument scanned: '-f./vdbench_config'
00:02:26.371 
00:02:26.371 Note: fwd=fwd15,threads=1,...
00:02:26.371 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd15,... 
00:02:26.372 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.372 
00:02:26.372 Note: Requesting threads across multiple fsds, operations, slaves or hosts 
00:02:26.372       may result in fractions of threads. 
00:02:26.372       There will be a minimum of one thread for each fsd, operation, 
00:02:26.372       slave or host, or integer truncation of the resulting thread count.
00:02:26.372       Contact the author of Vdbench if there are unexplained differences.
00:02:26.372 
00:02:26.372       Use general parameter 'fwd_thread_adjust=no' to cause Vdbench to abort instead. 
00:02:26.372 
00:02:26.372 
00:02:26.372 Note: fwd=fwd14,threads=1,...
00:02:26.372 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd14,... 
00:02:26.373 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.373 
00:02:26.373 Note: fwd=fwd13,threads=1,...
00:02:26.373 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd13,... 
00:02:26.373 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.373 
00:02:26.373 Note: fwd=fwd12,threads=1,...
00:02:26.373 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd12,... 
00:02:26.373 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.373 
00:02:26.374 Note: fwd=fwd17,threads=1,...
00:02:26.374 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd17,... 
00:02:26.374 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.374 
00:02:26.374 Note: fwd=fwd11,threads=1,...
00:02:26.374 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd11,... 
00:02:26.374 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.374 
00:02:26.374 Note: fwd=fwd19,threads=1,...
00:02:26.374 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd19,... 
00:02:26.375 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.375 
00:02:26.375 Note: fwd=fwd18,threads=1,...
00:02:26.375 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd18,... 
00:02:26.375 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.375 
00:02:26.375 Note: fwd=fwd16,threads=1,...
00:02:26.375 Note: rd=rd1,fwd=fwd16,... 
00:02:26.375 Note: Mismatch between threads requested (1) and used (3)
00:02:26.378 Anchor size: anchor=/vdbench2: dirs:            6; files:          400; bytes:     5.522g (5,929,369,600)
00:02:26.378 Anchor size: anchor=/vdbench3: dirs:            6; files:          400; bytes:     8.287g (8,898,150,400)
00:02:26.379 Anchor size: anchor=/vdbench1: dirs:            6; files:          400; bytes:     5.522g (5,929,369,600)
00:02:26.388 Estimated totals for all 3 anchors: dirs: 18; files: 1,200; bytes: 19.331g 
00:02:26.423 Starting slave: /tmp/vdbench/vdbench SlaveJvm -m localhost -n localhost-10-231002-00.02.26.279 -l localhost-0 -p 5570   
00:02:26.636 All slaves are now connected
00:02:28.001 Starting RD=format_for_rd1
00:02:28.840 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench2 mkdir complete.
00:02:28.853 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench1 mkdir complete.

Oct 02, 2023 ..Interval.. .ReqstdOps... ...cpu%...  read ....read..... ....write.... ..mb/sec... mb/sec .xfer.. ...mkdir.... ...rmdir.... ...create... ....open.... ...close.... ...delete... ..getattr... ..setattr...
                            rate   resp total  sys   pct   rate   resp   rate   resp  read write  total    size  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp
00:02:29.140            1 8697.0  0.302  19.1 15.6   0.0    0.0  0.000 8697.0  0.302  0.00  1079 1079.4  130143  12.0  0.031  15.0  0.146  68.0 41.391  84.0  0.444  68.0  0.026  1716  2.850   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:29.807 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench3 mkdir complete.
00:02:30.038            2  39556  0.398  74.1 60.3   0.0    0.0  0.000  39556  0.398  0.00  4906 4906.4  130064   6.0  0.031   3.0  0.114 337.0 40.159 345.0  0.206 337.0  0.035  84.0  8.720   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:31.027            3 5754.0  4.164  10.9 6.01   0.0    0.0  0.000 5754.0  4.164  0.00 715.6 715.64  130413   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  45.0 399.53  45.0  0.169  45.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:32.022            4 4810.0  4.871  13.3 7.23   0.0    0.0  0.000 4810.0  4.871  0.00 598.8 598.80  130538   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  34.0 690.86  34.0  6.353  34.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:33.017            5 3968.0  6.061  10.1 6.39   0.0    0.0  0.000 3968.0  6.061  0.00 493.9 493.96  130532   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  27.0 807.18  27.0  2.629  27.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:34.015            6 3381.0  7.021   5.5 3.56   0.0    0.0  0.000 3381.0  7.021  0.00 420.7 420.73  130484   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  25.0 829.43  25.0  0.164  25.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:35.014            7 2823.0  8.523   7.0 4.69   0.0    0.0  0.000 2823.0  8.523  0.00 351.1 351.12  130420   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  21.0 879.73  21.0  0.153  21.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:36.014            8 2768.0  8.679   5.8 3.62   0.0    0.0  0.000 2768.0  8.679  0.00 344.2 344.28  130420   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  20.0 1286.2  20.0  0.164  20.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:37.015            9 2674.0  9.019   6.3 4.17   0.0    0.0  0.000 2674.0  9.019  0.00 332.4 332.49  130381   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  19.0 1347.6  19.0  5.843  19.0  0.031   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:38.013           10 2623.0  9.084   6.8 4.48   0.0    0.0  0.000 2623.0  9.084  0.00 325.9 325.96  130308   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  21.0 1252.8  21.0  3.956  21.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:39.012           11 2552.0  9.425   5.4 3.60   0.0    0.0  0.000 2552.0  9.425  0.00 317.2 317.28  130365   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  20.0 1078.7  20.0  0.159  20.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:40.011           12 2454.0  9.470   3.8 2.47   0.0    0.0  0.000 2454.0  9.470  0.00 305.3 305.37  130482   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 955.13  17.0  0.163  17.0  0.032   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:41.011           13 2485.0  9.935   6.9 4.73   0.0    0.0  0.000 2485.0  9.935  0.00 308.8 308.83  130313   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  20.0 1265.9  20.0  0.151  20.0  0.030   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:42.013           14 2106.0 10.273   4.9 3.22   0.0    0.0  0.000 2106.0 10.273  0.00 261.7 261.79  130342   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  15.0 1500.2  15.0 12.405  15.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:43.011           15 2727.0  9.350   7.3 4.99   0.0    0.0  0.000 2727.0  9.350  0.00 339.1 339.12  130397   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  21.0 1449.3  21.0 33.646  21.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:44.011           16 2363.0 10.148   4.2 2.73   0.0    0.0  0.000 2363.0 10.148  0.00 293.6 293.61  130290   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  19.0 1430.7  19.0  0.148  19.0  0.026   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:44.029 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench1: Created 348 of 400 files (87.00%)
00:02:45.009           17 2364.0 10.191   7.3 4.80   0.0    0.0  0.000 2364.0 10.191  0.00 293.9 293.93  130375   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  18.0 1329.4  18.0  0.155  18.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:46.009           18 2312.0 10.366   5.4 3.54   0.0    0.0  0.000 2312.0 10.366  0.00 287.4 287.46  130375   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 1324.5  17.0  0.159  17.0  0.031   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:47.019           19 2192.0 10.735   3.8 2.34   0.0    0.0  0.000 2192.0 10.735  0.00 272.8 272.81  130503   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  16.0 1400.5  16.0  9.187  16.0  0.030   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:48.009           20 2208.0 10.988   6.1 4.10   0.0    0.0  0.000 2208.0 10.988  0.00 274.4 274.42  130320   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 1567.5  17.0  3.517  17.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:49.010           21 2109.0 11.279   6.2 4.28   0.0    0.0  0.000 2109.0 11.279  0.00 262.2 262.27  130400   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  14.0 1500.9  14.0  0.158  14.0  0.036   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:50.008           22 2194.0 10.990   7.8 5.42   0.0    0.0  0.000 2194.0 10.990  0.00 272.8 272.87  130412   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 1481.5  17.0  0.154  17.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:51.008           23 2237.0 10.724   7.7 5.41   0.0    0.0  0.000 2237.0 10.724  0.00 278.0 278.05  130335   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  18.0 1439.7  18.0  0.152  18.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:52.008           24 2111.0 10.533   8.2 5.59   0.0    0.0  0.000 2111.0 10.533  0.00 262.3 262.34  130309   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 1410.2  13.0  0.153  17.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:52.578 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench1 create complete.
00:02:53.008           25 1739.0 10.069   7.5 5.08   0.0    0.0  0.000 1739.0 10.069  0.00 216.0 216.07  130282   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  15.0 1385.6  11.0 44.048  15.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:54.008           26 1593.0  9.995   7.0 4.84   0.0    0.0  0.000 1593.0  9.995  0.00 198.1 198.16  130434   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  12.0 1404.0  12.0  0.162  12.0  0.031   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:55.009           27 1649.0  9.728   7.2 4.82   0.0    0.0  0.000 1649.0  9.728  0.00 205.3 205.35  130577   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 1400.5  11.0  0.158  11.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:56.009           28 1683.0  9.481   4.9 3.28   0.0    0.0  0.000 1683.0  9.481  0.00 209.5 209.52  130539   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 1406.8  11.0  0.143  11.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:57.008           29 1604.0  9.949   3.9 2.59   0.0    0.0  0.000 1604.0  9.949  0.00 199.7 199.77  130591   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  12.0 1360.8  12.0  0.439  12.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:58.008           30  979.0  8.343   4.1 2.70   0.0    0.0  0.000  979.0  8.343  0.00 122.1 122.16  130846   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   6.0 1382.4   6.0 22.055   6.0  0.033   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000

Oct 02, 2023 ..Interval.. .ReqstdOps... ...cpu%...  read ....read..... ....write.... ..mb/sec... mb/sec .xfer.. ...mkdir.... ...rmdir.... ...create... ....open.... ...close.... ...delete... ..getattr... ..setattr...
                            rate   resp total  sys   pct   rate   resp   rate   resp  read write  total    size  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp
00:02:59.009           31 1003.0  7.968   5.5 3.75   0.0    0.0  0.000 1003.0  7.968  0.00 125.2 125.20  130888   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   5.0 1367.8   5.0  0.178   5.0  0.031   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:02:59.388 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench3: Created 216 of 400 files (54.00%)
00:03:00.009           32 1387.0 22.643   5.3 3.57   0.0    0.0  0.000 1387.0 22.643  0.00 172.7 172.75  130596   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   9.0 2402.9   9.0  0.170   9.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:01.019           33 1213.0 13.084   4.9 3.40   0.0    0.0  0.000 1213.0 13.084  0.00 151.1 151.15  130663   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   9.0 1969.5   9.0  0.161   9.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:02.008           34 1403.0 11.631   9.7 7.17   0.0    0.0  0.000 1403.0 11.631  0.00 174.7 174.75  130601   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   9.0 2354.9   9.0  0.153   9.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:03.007           35 1748.0  9.201   6.7 4.46   0.0    0.0  0.000 1748.0  9.201  0.00 217.6 217.64  130558   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 1760.6  11.0 11.256  11.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:04.008           36 1783.0  8.966   3.2 1.89   0.0    0.0  0.000 1783.0  8.966  0.00 222.0 222.03  130573   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  13.0 1315.2  13.0  0.155  13.0  0.026   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:05.009           37 1801.0  8.881   5.2 3.46   0.0    0.0  0.000 1801.0  8.881  0.00 224.4 224.43  130664   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 1313.6  11.0  0.147  11.0  0.026   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:06.008           38 1851.0  8.606   4.5 3.03   0.0    0.0  0.000 1851.0  8.606  0.00 230.4 230.41  130527   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  14.0 1306.9  14.0  0.153  14.0  0.026   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:07.010           39 1828.0  8.757   6.8 4.58   0.0    0.0  0.000 1828.0  8.757  0.00 227.4 227.46  130475   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  14.0 1259.2  14.0  0.149  14.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:08.008           40 2012.0  7.973   6.2 4.16   0.0    0.0  0.000 2012.0  7.973  0.00 250.2 250.23  130408   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  14.0 1091.5  14.0  0.149  14.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:09.008           41 2169.0  7.369   7.0 4.67   0.0    0.0  0.000 2169.0  7.369  0.00 269.7 269.78  130422   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  16.0 1052.7  16.0  0.165  16.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:10.008           42 2328.0  6.873   4.4 2.85   0.0    0.0  0.000 2328.0  6.873  0.00 289.6 289.62  130450   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  17.0 963.30  17.0  0.165  17.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:10.649 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench2 create complete.
00:03:11.008           43 1478.0  7.589   4.5 2.95   0.0    0.0  0.000 1478.0  7.589  0.00 183.6 183.60  130254   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  15.0 985.06   7.0  0.160  15.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:12.008           44  974.0  8.199   4.9 3.07   0.0    0.0  0.000  974.0  8.199  0.00 121.5 121.54  130844   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   6.0 1379.5   6.0  0.151   6.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:13.007           45  884.0  9.120   3.4 2.32   0.0    0.0  0.000  884.0  9.120  0.00 110.3 110.36  130905   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   4.0 1441.0   3.0  0.168   4.0  0.030   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:14.008           46 1102.0  7.234   6.4 4.25   0.0    0.0  0.000 1102.0  7.234  0.00 137.5 137.50  130837   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   7.0 1472.3   8.0  0.159   7.0  0.032   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:14.666 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench3: Created 312 of 400 files (78.00%)
00:03:15.008           47 1433.0  5.568   4.8 3.20   0.0    0.0  0.000 1433.0  5.568  0.00 178.8 178.84  130866   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   8.0 1073.9   8.0  0.170   8.0  0.030   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:16.007           48 1308.0  6.132   3.3 2.20   0.0    0.0  0.000 1308.0  6.132  0.00 163.2 163.22  130846   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   8.0 960.74   8.0  0.156   8.0  0.035   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:17.007           49 1311.0  6.010   5.6 3.58   0.0    0.0  0.000 1311.0  6.010  0.00 163.5 163.59  130847   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   8.0 1067.3   8.0  0.153   8.0  0.028   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:18.008           50 1588.0  4.862   4.4 2.76   0.0    0.0  0.000 1588.0  4.862  0.00 198.2 198.22  130886   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   8.0 909.54   7.0  0.155   8.0  0.029   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:19.007           51 1757.0  4.722   5.1 3.27   0.0    0.0  0.000 1757.0  4.722  0.00 219.2 219.24  130841   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 816.91  12.0  4.659  11.0  0.025   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:20.007           52 2488.0  3.181   8.1 5.51   0.0    0.0  0.000 2488.0  3.181  0.00 310.4 310.47  130849   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  15.0 610.11  15.0  0.161  15.0  0.027   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:21.008           53 1976.0  4.035   5.6 3.82   0.0    0.0  0.000 1976.0  4.035  0.00 246.6 246.61  130866   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  11.0 653.63  11.0  0.189  11.0  0.024   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:22.007           54 2763.0  2.846   8.1 5.50   0.0    0.0  0.000 2763.0  2.846  0.00 344.8 344.81  130858   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  16.0 514.36  16.0  0.160  16.0  0.025   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:22.302 localhost-0: anchor=/vdbench3 create complete.
00:03:23.008           55  860.0  2.269   7.5 5.16   0.0    0.0  0.000  860.0  2.269  0.00 107.1 107.15  130643   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  10.0 448.80   2.0  0.168  10.0  0.025   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:23.016     avg_2-55 2786.4  6.181   6.8 4.61   0.0    0.0  0.000 2786.4  6.181  0.00 346.5 346.50  130396   0.1  0.031   0.1  0.114  20.9 825.49  20.6  2.278  20.9  0.030   1.6  8.720   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:23.016     std_2-55 5176.4 21.448                                5176.4 21.448                              0.8  0.016   0.4  0.010  44.4 711.93  45.6 16.119  44.4  0.171  11.4  7.877                          
00:03:23.017     max_2-55  39556 2104.0                                 39556 2104.0                              6.0  0.081   3.0  0.856 337.0 4414.0 345.0 221.23 337.0  5.755  84.0 36.293                          
00:03:23.165 
00:03:23.165 Miscellaneous statistics:
00:03:23.165 (These statistics do not include activity between the last reported interval and shutdown.)
00:03:23.165 FILE_CREATES        Files created:                                1,200         21/sec
00:03:23.165 DIRECTORY_CREATES   Directories created:                             18          0/sec
00:03:23.165 FILE_DELETES        Files deleted:                                1,800         32/sec
00:03:23.165 DIRECTORY_DELETES   Directories deleted:                             18          0/sec
00:03:23.165 WRITE_OPENS         Files opened for write activity:              1,200         21/sec
00:03:23.165 DIR_EXISTS          Directory may not exist (yet):                   15          0/sec
00:03:23.166 FILE_CLOSES         Close requests:                               1,200         21/sec
00:03:23.166 
00:03:25.001 Starting RD=rd1; elapsed=30; fwdrate=max. For loops: None

Oct 02, 2023 ..Interval.. .ReqstdOps... ...cpu%...  read ....read..... ....write.... ..mb/sec... mb/sec .xfer.. ...mkdir.... ...rmdir.... ...create... ....open.... ...close.... ...delete... ..getattr... ..setattr...
                            rate   resp total  sys   pct   rate   resp   rate   resp  read write  total    size  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp  rate   resp
00:03:26.021            1  37259  0.107  14.0 6.22  48.9 5911.0  0.002 6181.0  0.011 23.09 24.14  47.23    4096   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000 169.0  0.189  7044  0.128  7038  0.010 424.0  4.016  5301  0.110  5191  0.118
00:03:27.011            2  17400  0.159  15.9 11.7   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  1477  0.032  6396  0.018  6396  0.002  1973  1.303 540.0  0.012 618.0  0.014
00:03:28.011            3  14366  0.113   6.4 4.50   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000  3589  0.027  3589  0.013  3589  0.002  3599  0.411   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:29.011            4 1966.0  0.735   1.1 0.38   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000 655.0  0.986 655.0  0.978 655.0  0.001   1.0 158.59   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:30.012            5    0.0  0.000   1.5 0.63   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:31.011            6    0.0  0.000   1.4 0.69   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:32.012            7    0.0  0.000   2.3 0.56   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:33.011            8    0.0  0.000   1.8 0.75   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:34.011            9    0.0  0.000   1.0 0.38   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:35.011           10    0.0  0.000   0.9 0.31   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:36.011           11    0.0  0.000   0.8 0.25   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:37.011           12    0.0  0.000   0.7 0.19   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:38.010           13    0.0  0.000   0.7 0.25   0.0    0.0  0.000    0.0  0.000  0.00  0.00   0.00       0   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000   0.0  0.000
00:03:38.887 
00:03:38.887 Message from slave localhost-0: 
00:03:38.887 file=/vdbench3/vdb.1_1.dir/vdb.2_1.dir/vdb_f0001.file,busy=true
00:03:38.888 file=/vdbench3/vdb.1_1.dir/vdb.2_1.dir/vdb_f0002.file,busy=true
00:03:38.888 Thread: FwgThread create /vdbench3 rd=rd1 For loops: None
00:03:38.888 
00:03:38.888 last_ok_request: Mon Oct 02 00:03:28 CST 2023
00:03:38.888 Duration: 10.81 seconds
00:03:38.888 consecutive_blocks: 10001
00:03:38.888 last_block:         FILE_MAY_NOT_EXIST  File may not exist (yet)
00:03:38.888 operation:          create
00:03:38.888 
00:03:38.889 Do you maybe have more threads running than that you have 
00:03:38.889 files and therefore some threads ultimately give up after 10000 tries?
00:03:38.895 *
00:03:38.895 ******************************************************
00:03:38.895 * Slave localhost-0 aborting: Too many thread blocks *
00:03:38.895 ******************************************************
00:03:38.895 *
00:03:41.021 
00:03:41.021 Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated. 
00:03:41.021 
00:03:41.021 Slave aborted. Abort message received: 
00:03:41.021 Too many thread blocks
00:03:41.021 
00:03:41.021 Look at file localhost-0.stdout.html for more information.
00:03:41.523 
00:03:41.523 Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated. 
00:03:41.523 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated. 
        at Vdb.common.failure(common.java:350)
        at Vdb.SlaveStarter.startSlave(SlaveStarter.java:188)
        at Vdb.SlaveStarter.run(SlaveStarter.java:47)
```